# Convert Loadrunner File Parameter to Java string for payload

Tags: java, performance, loadrunner

I have a java virtual user script that is sending a payload request. I am trying to use values from a file to send via a loadrunner file parameter.

here is the payload:

```
private static final String PAYLOAD =
            "<ips_cad_mdt>\n" + 
            "   <SignOnRequest>\n" + 
            "       <DestApplication>hhhh</DestApplication>\n" + 
            "       <OrigApplication>hhh</OrigApplication>\n" + 
            "       <SessionRef>3</SessionRef>\n" + 
            "       <Aliasing>1234</Aliasing>\n" + 
            "   </SignOnRequest>\n" + 
            "</ips_cad_mdt>";
```

I would like to use something like the following:

```
private static final String PAYLOAD =
            "<ips_cad_mdt>\n" + 
            "   <SignOnRequest>\n" + 
            "       <DestApplication>hhh</DestApplication>\n" + 
            "       <OrigApplication>hhh</OrigApplication>\n" + 
            "       <SessionRef>3</SessionRef>\n" + 
            "       <Aliasing>”+lr.eval_string(“{AliasId}”)+”</Aliasing>\n" + 
            "   </SignOnRequest>\n" + 
            "</ips_cad_mdt>";
```

for some reason i cant see any output for this value. do i need to declare a variable: e.g. lr.save_string("AliasId", "{AliasId}");

an example of this would help loads. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an error in the code completion in VuGen. The parameters should be reversed and without the {} in save_string.

```
    lr.save_string("1234","myId");
    lr.message(lr.eval_string("{myId}"));
```

In the documentation it is correct - https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.55/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#FuncRef/c_vuser/lrFr_lr_save_string.htm?Highlight=lr_save_string

I asked the responsible team to fix the code completion in VuGen so you will be able to see this change in one of the future releases.